# Can someone please tell me why the 20 second delay is not working here?

Tags: css

Can someone please tell me why the 20 second delay is not working here?

It actually shows the animation for 20 seconds then restarts it!

Thank you.

### CSS

```
#birds2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 470px;
    height: 93px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-animation: birds2_anim 120s linear normal;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal, horizontal ;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-delay:20s;
}   
@-webkit-keyframes birds2_anim {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(500px, 150px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-700px, -100px); }
}
```

### Javascript

```
var container7 = document.getElementById("birdsContainer");
container7.appendChild(createCbird());
function createCbird() {
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.id = "birds2";    
image.src = "Images/Weather/birds/birds1.gif";
return image;
```

Comment: as it stands this should give you a 120s animation with a delayed start by 20secs. To really be able to debug your code, you should provide a running example that includes the code you actually use. (When abstracting the code for a (SO)question one sometimes misses the crucial point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delay / duration both work well, but you might be looking for these properties :

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

The first one set the end of your animation to the last frame (default is first frame), while the second one make it run only once.

### Edit

As you want it to be positioned as the first frame of your animation, add

```
#birds2 {
    left: 500px;
    top: 150px;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes birds2_anim {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }      /* Set 0px and 0px */
    /* Or you can simply remove the property, leaving empty brackets for 0% */
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-700px, -100px); }
}
```

[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/bBwx9/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, it does actually delay it for 20 seconds but for that 20 seconds I see the animation in the center of the screen (set to start 500px right (off screen)), I don't understand why I see it for 20 seconds then it disappears and restarts from the correct position.

Comment: I use it with this .js function [CODE]var container7 = document.getElementById("birdsContainer");
container7.appendChild(createCbird());
function createCbird() {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.id = "birds2"; 
    image.src = "Images/Weather/birds/birds1.gif";
    return image;
}[/CODE]

Comment: You set the position at the top left corner of the parent element in your CSS (`top:0px` / `left:0px`), and after 20s you set its position to `left:500px` / `top:150px`. Set `top:150px` and `left:500px` if you want it to  be positioned as the first frame of your animation.

Comment: Thanks Bigood, that sounds like what is causing my issue, I'm kicking myself now LOL...

Comment: I try to add the js code in post 1 but it was added into the css code, sorry. Then there is just the div in the html.

Comment: @user2253720 If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted for future visitors to see!

Comment: No, didn't solve it, if I set left to 500px then the animation starts at 1000px. I just had to remove the delay as can't find a fix.